# Decrypt TCB, TAD file

Tags: encryption, decode

I'm developing a Chinese game, it was released 10 years ago. I need decrypt two this files in the client game. My purpose is to redesign the game menu.

This is code in exchange.tcb
https://filebin.net/qs7d4ukdw8gxxde9
[image]

And this is code in exchange.dat

https://filebin.net/lrsu3t1kc2zv2i8f
[image]

I did try many decrypt tools but failed. Any recommendation? Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't think either of these files are "encrypted", because they look far too regular for that. Probably they are just using some proprietary format. I opened them in a hex editor, but apart from the first 3 or 4 bytes, I can't make heads or tails of them. If you have the game's source code, just look at how the files are decoded. Otherwise, you're probably looking at a serious reverse engineering task.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I think so. Do you know what software can open TAD files? Please help me.

Comment: Any hex editor can "open" the file and show you the raw contents. But most likely, that game you're working on is the only software that knows how to interpret those contents.